# Automatically change task status in TFS upon creation or acceptance of review request

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs

I have a following problem at hand: need to find a way to automatically change task status in TFS upon creation or acceptance of review request. Or, at least manual process but done in the same interface with least effort possible.

Something like an action available to choose, for a reviewer, when accepting the review request, that would set the Status of associated Work Item to a specific one used by the team, for Example "Review in Progress".

Is that possible? I know something can be done with TFS templates but can't figure it out.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

you can write an event driven TFS plugin to change the status of the work item upon e.g. creation.

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/assafstone/2011/07/29/how-to-write-a-robust-tfs-server-plugin-with-job-extensions/